# SQL Comma Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error

I'm working on an assignment for school for SQL and this is the query I'm making.

```
SELECT 
    Regions.RegionName, Countries.CountryName, 
    (Employees.LastName + ', ' + Employees.FirstName) AS EmployeeName, 
    (EmployeeTitles.Title + ' ' + CAST (Employees.Level AS VARCHAR), 
    Employees.Salary
FROM 
    Regions, 
    Countries, 
    Employees, 
    EmployeeTitles
WHERE 
    Regions.RegionID = Countries.RegionID AND
    Countries.CountryID = Employees.CountryID AND
    Employees.TitleID = EMployeeTitles.TitleID
ORDER BY 
    RegionName, 
    CountryName, 
    LastName, 
    Title, 
    Salary;
```

The comma that is giving me the error is right after the "Cast(Employee.Level AS VARCHAR)" and is giving me an error saying "Incorrect syntax near ','-

Thanks.

Comment: Specify the varchar length. Also count the `(`'s and `)`'s. Same number?

Comment: Use proper join syntax

Comment: To elaborate on join syntax see this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Especially since you are in school you should unlearn that style before it is difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed a closing parenthesis, before that comma.

```
(EmployeeTitles.Title + ' ' + CAST (Employees.Level AS VARCHAR),
```

should become

```
(EmployeeTitles.Title + ' ' + CAST (Employees.Level AS VARCHAR)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
select r.RegionName, c.CountryName, 
       concat(e.LastName, ',', e.FirstName) AS EmployeeName,
       concat(et.Title, ',', CAST(e.Level AS VARCHAR(255))) AS [??],
       e.Salary
from Regions r
inner join Countries c on c.RegionID  = r.RegionID 
inner join Employees e on e.CountryID  = c.CountryID 
inner join EmployeeTitles et on et.TitleID = e.TitleID
order by r.RegionName, c.CountryName, e.LastName, e.title, e.salary;
```

Always define length while using `cast/convert()` function. Here is a interesting post on it you can refer [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: It was just a parenthesis I missed.